# Black box testing IOS10 from an .IPA

Tags: ios, automated-tests

Is there any way to automate the black box functional testing of an IOS app? I have NO access to the source code - it's a commercial app, that my organisation needs to test before we use it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather generic, but your best option is to use Appium: http://appium.io/